# Session is not active even when PHPSESSID is set and session_start() has been called PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to create a page that logs out the users on my website, but when I try to reinitialize the session, my page keeps saying `Warning: session_regenerate_id(): Cannot regenerate session id - session is not active`. The code that starts the session:

```
try {
  if (!isset($_SESSION) or session_id() == "") {
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['auth']) or $_COOKIE['auth'] != 'NO') {
      $_COOKIE['auth'] = 'NO';
    }
  }
} catch (Error $e) {
  echo "Caught Error: $e";
}
```

The logout page code:

```
try {
    unset($_SESSION);
    session_regenerate_id(true);
} catch (Error $e) {
    echo "Caught Error: $e";
}
```

There are not `session_destroy()`s or anything like that anywhere else on my website (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18551030/error-session-destroy-trying-to-destroy-uninitialized-session)), and I can see that the *PHPSESSID* cookie is set and after clearing the cookies gets set again after a page refresh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just know that sessions should be started right at the beginning of the code

So do something like this:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id(true);

    if($_SESSION['name_of_the_session'] == false){
        header("Location: please_make_login.php"); //If doesn't exists the session, redirect user to the login page
        exit();
    }
   
    try {
        if (!isset($_COOKIE['auth']) or $_COOKIE['auth'] != 'NO') {
          $_COOKIE['auth'] = 'NO';
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Caught Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**Logout**

```
<?php

    session_start(); //It'll see if exists a session
    session_destroy(); //Then will destroy the session
    header("Location: index.php"); //And redirect to a page named index.php & finish the process
    exit();
```

If you want to work with sessions, then initialize them first in every PHP script, and after initializing the session, regenerate the id, a quick example:

```
<?php
 
 session_start();
 session_regenerate_id(true); //I recommend to use true

 $some_variable = $_SESSION['name_of_the_session'];

 //Don't forget to check if the session exists, if the user really started a session!
 
 if($some_variable == false){
   header("Location: please_make_login.php"); //Redirect the user to a page because the user doesn't started a session
   exit();
 }

 echo $some_variable; //Echo the value of the session, it'll only echo if really exists
```

Comment: Please tell me if you understand, if you still have the problem, I am here to help you

Comment: Thanks for your help. I still get the same ```session is not active``` error even when explicitly calling ```session_start()``` on the page. All cookies and variables seem to set correctly in the Session and even was able to echo variables from the Session.

Comment: 1 - Check for any white space before opening the `<?php` tag and closing it. If there is any blank space, remove. 2 - Make sure you do NOTHING before using `session_regenerate_id()`, as I told you, in the first lines of code start the sessions and then regenerate them. 3 - Also try to use `ob_start()` at the beginning of the PHP script

Comment: Please let me know if you have solved your problem, I am here to help you!

Comment: Oh. I misunderstood. What I am trying to achieve is a ```session_destroy()``` while regenerating the session. I'll change my code for that and report back. Thanks.

Comment: Very well! Got it now?

Comment: Not yet. It still has the same error, but I am trying to make a page where that user is actually signed in to see if that is the issue. Last hope really.

Comment: Do not lose hope. It all seems very confusing, you are probably doing something wrong, I would like to help you!
Could you please add more details to your question?
You said you want to create a page to disconnect users, well, I created a script that does that. If your code isn't working, maybe it's because you didn't name a session? Is what it seems!

Comment: I never knew I had to name a session. After I get the login page fixed, I'll definitely try it out. Thanks!

Comment: what would ```$_SESSION['name_of_the_session'];``` be set to? I don't see this being set anywhere in your answer. could I do ```if (session_name()) {//session active}```?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222561/discussion-between-anne-rebb-and-notanerd).

Comment: Just making sure: If you start a session on one page, It transfers over to the next?

Comment: Yes, but for that on this "next" page, `session_start()` must be enabled, only then can you work with sessions

Comment: This is what solved it for me. Thanks for all your help!